# Modifying JSON Object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

My API responds my call with the following JSON structure:

```
[
    {
        "order": {
            "total": "240.0",
            "completed_at": 1358432545000
        }
    },
    {
        "order": {
            "total": "720.0",
            "completed_at": 1359474090000
        }
    }
]
```

However, I want this JSON to be structured like this in order to use my data in Flot Graphs:

```
   {
        "label":"Order",
        "dataBar":[
            [
                1358432545000,
                240.0
            ],
            [
                1325635200000 ,
                720.0
            ]
        ]
    }
```

I've tried the following code, but it returns all data with comma separated, without '[' and ']'

```
var flotData = $.map(API_Response, function(i){ return [i.order.completed_at, parseInt(i.order.total)] });
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you modifying this json object usign JQuery? Create an object out of existing json, create a new empty object and add values to the new one. Then create JSON out of the new object.

Comment: I don't see why 3 users voted to close this as not a real question. It looks very real to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var data2 = {
    label: 'Order',
    dataBar: data.map(function(v){return [
         v.order.completed_at,
         parseFloat(v.order.total)
    ]})
};
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ivaseh/1) (open the console to see data2)

But please note there is nothing that can be called a "JSON structure" or a "JSON object".

What you have is a plain JavaScript object, even if it was sent to your browser encoded in JSON.

---

Now supposing you don't know the property of your object is called `order`, then you can do it with

```
var label;
for (var k in data[0]) {
   label = k[0].toUpperCase()+k.slice(1);
   break;
}
var data2 = {
    label: label,
    dataBar: data.map(function(v){return [
         v[k].completed_at,
         parseFloat(v[k].total)
    ]})
};
```

(It would be cleaner without support for IE 8, as I could have used `Object.keys`.)

Comment: Aren't `completed_at` and `total` properties of a deeper object?

Comment: @Boaz You're right. I fixed ([and tested](http://jsbin.com/ivaseh/1)) the answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. For general usage, is there any way to automate .order part, in case of json data changes ?

Comment: @CanCeylan See edit regarding automatic building of the label.

Comment: No, what I mean is, if the json has the following value: 
"SOMETHING_DIFFERENT_THAN_ORDER": {
            "total": "240.0",
            "completed_at": 1358432545000
        }. So we won't be able to reach the values by writing v.order